# How to use Pygame's sprite_collide_mask method to detect direction of collision?

Tags: python, pygame, 2d, collision-detection

So what I'm trying to do is to create a pool table game using Pygame, with balls bouncing off the edges of the pool table like so.

I have png image of a pool table like so:

[image]

The white parts are transparent, and so when a mask is made, and the ball is placed inside the transparent part, it collides using Pygame's `sprite.collide_mask(ballsprite, tablesprite)` function. The background is a dark-greenish color.

However, the `sprite.collide_mask` function returns a point of collision, and I don't know how to calculate the resultant direction that the ball should travel in, since I only have the ball's starting point (since the last collision) and the point of collision to work with.

I know I should calculate a normal vector to the surface, but how am I supposed to do this when Pygame's mask collision doesn't provide any functions to do this?

One solution I thought of is to create a **rectangular bounding box** that approximates the white (transparent) area. But, if I set the rectangle as transparent, then, nothing will ever collide (if I use the mask method), and if I set the rectangle to the same color as my background, then it will always register a collision, since the ball is in the rectangle's 'rect'.

How should I go about handling collision detection, and handling the change of direction for my game?

(I can provide my code if need be)

Comment: [pygame.math.Vector2](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) has `normalize()`

Comment: I think you could use point returned from `collide_mask` and object's center point to create direction vector .

Comment: @furas that was what I was doing. However, how am I then supposed to calculate the normal vector with the edges of the pool table- normalize does not calculate a normal vector - it creates a unit vector

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be better to create a billiards game with the help of the physics library [Pymunk](http://pymunk.org). It can be a bit difficult to get started, but then you don't have to implement the physics on your own.

I've got an example here, just to demonstrate how the code could look like. You'll have to familiarize yourself with the library to understand everything. (Steer the ball with the WASD keys.)

```
import math

import pygame as pg
import pymunk as pm
from pymunk import Vec2d


def flipy(p):
    """Convert chipmunk coordinates to pygame coordinates."""
    return Vec2d(p[0], -p[1]+600)


class Ball(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, space):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((60, 60), pg.SRCALPHA)
        pg.draw.circle(self.image, pg.Color('steelblue2'), (30, 30), 29)
        pg.draw.circle(self.image, pg.Color('black'), (30, 10), 5)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.orig_image = self.image
        # Create the physics body and shape of this object.
        self.body = pm.Body()
        self.shape = pm.Circle(self.body, radius=30)
        self.shape.density = .0001
        self.shape.friction = .1
        self.shape.elasticity = .99
        self.body.position = pos
        # Add them to the Pymunk space.
        self.space = space
        self.space.add(self.body, self.shape)
        print(self.body.mass)

        self.accel_forw = False
        self.accel_back = False
        self.turn_left = False
        self.turn_right = False
        self.topspeed = 1790
        self.angle = 0

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_w:
                self.accel_forw = True
            if event.key == pg.K_a:
                self.turn_left = True
            if event.key == pg.K_d:
                self.turn_right = True
            if event.key == pg.K_s:
                self.accel_back = True
        if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pg.K_w:
                self.accel_forw = False
            if event.key == pg.K_a:
                self.turn_left = False
            if event.key == pg.K_d:
                self.turn_right = False
            if event.key == pg.K_s:
                self.accel_back = False

    def update(self, dt):
        # Accelerate the pymunk body of this sprite.
        if self.accel_forw and self.body.velocity.length < self.topspeed:
            self.body.apply_force_at_local_point(Vec2d(0, 624), Vec2d(0, 0))
        if self.accel_back and self.body.velocity.length < self.topspeed:
            self.body.apply_force_at_local_point(Vec2d(0, -514), Vec2d(0, 0))
        if self.turn_left and self.body.velocity.length < self.topspeed:
            self.body.angle += .1
            self.body.angular_velocity = 0
        if self.turn_right and self.body.velocity.length < self.topspeed:
            self.body.angle -= .1
            self.body.angular_velocity = 0
        # Rotate the image of the sprite.
        self.angle = self.body.angle
        self.rect.center = flipy(self.body.position)
        self.image = pg.transform.rotozoom(
            self.orig_image, math.degrees(self.body.angle), 1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)


class Wall(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, verts, space, mass, *sprite_groups):
        super().__init__(*sprite_groups)
        # Determine the width and height of the surface.
        width = max(v[0] for v in verts)
        height = max(v[1] for v in verts)
        self.image = pg.Surface((width, height), pg.SRCALPHA)
        pg.draw.polygon(self.image, pg.Color('sienna1'), verts)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)

        moment = pm.moment_for_poly(mass, verts)
        self.body = pm.Body(mass, moment, pm.Body.STATIC)
        # Need to transform the vertices for the pymunk poly shape,
        # so that they fit to the image vertices.
        verts2 = [(x, -y) for x, y in verts]
        self.shape = pm.Poly(self.body, verts2, radius=2)
        self.shape.friction = 0.1
        self.shape.elasticity = .92
        self.body.position = flipy(pos)
        self.space = space
        self.space.add(self.shape)


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.done = False
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.bg_color = pg.Color(60, 60, 60)

        self.space = pm.Space()
        self.space.gravity = Vec2d(0.0, 0.0)
        self.space.damping = .4

        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()

        self.ball = Ball((300, 300), self.space)
        self.ball2 = Ball((400, 300), self.space)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.ball, self.ball2)
        # Position and vertices tuples for the walls.
        vertices = [
            ([10, 80], ((0, 0), (200, 0), (90, 500), (0, 500))),
            ([400, 250], ((40, 80), (200, 0), (170, 90), (10, 170))),
            ([600, 450], ((20, 40), (300, 0), (300, 120), (10, 100))),
            ([760, 10], ((0, 0), (30, 0), (30, 420), (0, 400))),
            ([10, 10], ((0, 0), (760, 0), (700, 60), (0, 60))),
            ([10, 580], ((0, 0), (760, 0), (700, 60), (0, 60))),
            ]

        for pos, verts in vertices:
            Wall(pos, verts, self.space, 1, self.all_sprites)

    def run(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(30) / 1000
            self.handle_events()
            self.run_logic()
            self.draw()

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True

            self.ball.handle_event(event)

    def run_logic(self):
        self.space.step(1/60)
        self.all_sprites.update(self.dt)

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    Game().run()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look into that.